# Roots of words. How better learn every word in English?

Tags: dictionaries

I'm learning English. For the first five years it was a school program, a gramma. I bring from this, that I don't know language very well, because, simply, do not know **words**.

I'm partially remember rules, [gerund](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerund), etc.

But I don't have enough skill with speaking, because I simply don't know how to name everything around me. I didn't know that a sprout is a sprout, a stool is a stool, etc.

As I know, every language was born from very deep ancients. Poor ancient's peoples name everything around by the same names, simple change the suffixes and the prefixes.

That is why I'm looking for **short dictionary**, that I should know, that contain only roots of words.

No matter that words migrated from India or Rome will be skipped in this light.

Only roots of English words. *Plus, it would be super great, to have a tree of childes of this roots.*

Could you provide me with the right dictionary?

Comment: I don't think it's at all likely that you need to "learn more words". Both your question title and text strongly suggest that what you really need to do is learn ***how to use*** the words you already know.

Comment: Are you talking about gramma?

Comment: As it happens, the fact that your spelling isn't very good (it's *grammar*, not *gramma*) wasn't what I had in mind. My point is your (written) English isn't actually very good, but I think I could say with absolute certainty that no-one would think that just because you might happen to have a limited vocabulary. Anyone could pass for a native speaker if they only knew how to use a couple of thousand English words - or even less.

Comment: http://xkcd.com/1133/

Comment: Well, with only 2000 words, you'd be forced to make a lot of unnatural word choices...  Heck, even *unnatural* barely makes the cut for top 10,000.  I think speakers should aim for 20,000 if they want to sound fluent.

Comment: @Jim Nice one! :)

Comment: @Jim, what is it? Comics about Rocket? Could, somebody give me true link to the list of all english dictionaries, I'll chose one for myself by myself.

Comment: @user9885 In my opinion, that webcomic is a nice once because, as stated in the picture, it is: *explained using only ten thousand words people use most often*. --For a list of well-known dictionaries, there is one here in ELL's meta: http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/a/739/3281. You can take a look there, but I'm not quite sure if any of them will serve your specific need (short dictionary, that contain only roots of words).

Comment: I am not sure if you are looking for a [dictionary](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/contain) that have word families.

Comment: @DamkerngT. It uses the awkward *ten hundred*, actually.  I'm curious which frequency list he used.  In COCA's list, *thousand* is in the top thousand (at #651), but *breathe* is not (at #2278).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a resource request.

Answer (score 5):

There are dictionaries of English roots, but I cannot find one which confines itself to Old English (‘Anglo-Saxon’, we used to call it) roots. There's a list on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_words_of_Anglo-Saxon_origin) of English words of Anglo-Saxon  origin.

In any case, I'm afraid a list of English ‘roots’ would be of very little use to you.

First, while it is true that many of the most frequently used words (97 of the first 100 on one list I consulted) derive from Old English, a large number of these are ‘function’ words—prepositions, conjunctions, pronouns and auxiliary verbs—which you probably know already: *to*, *by*, *and*, *him*, *can*, *may*. On the other hand, many words of Anglo-Saxon origin, though still part of the lexicon, are very rare in ordinary discourse: *wether*, for instance, or *atheling*.

Second, these are the oldest words in the language, and because of extensive changes in the sound structure of the language, some of which are and some of which are not reflected in modern spelling, they have in many cases changed substantially from their original form. Moreover, Old English morphology often employed change of vowels rather than affixes to express grammatical distinctions, and such differences have provoked different courses of evolution. In consequence, words deriving from the same root often show no discernible relationship today. For instance, it would be of little help to you to know the Anglo-Saxon root *myrig-*, whose modern descendants are *merry* and *mirth*; or *nēah*, whose modern descendants are *near*, *next* and *nigh*.

Third, Old English ‘roots’ have not been particularly ‘productive’ in Middle and Modern English. Over the last eight hundred years most new vocabulary has come about not by recycling and combining Old English roots but by recycling and combining roots from French, Latin and Greek. In particular, English makes little use of ‘native’ suffixes and prefixes; instead, we combine words into phrases like *keep up with* and *chief executive officer*.

So even if you could find a dictionary of the sort you describe I doubt it would be as helpful as you hope. I suggest that you would do much better to immerse yourself as much as you can in English writings and conversations ***which deal with the things that you want to write and talk about***. That will provide you a useful vocabulary instead of an arbitrary list.